# Remote desktop use only one monitor at home to match my remote setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, display-settings

I've searched for this a lot and everyone seems to want the opposite of what I'm looking for.

In my office setup I have two monitors, but before being sent to work from home I unplugged one so I wouldn't have to keep switching display at home, on LogMeIn.

We've now been setup on the MS RDP connection and I now have a second monitor at home. When I connect to my work PC through RDP, the display is taking over both of my monitors at home, even though I only have one plugged into my work PC. Effectively stretching the desktop over both, but then I can't use the desktop space displaying on the second monitor.

The thing is, I don't want to. I want the RDP to only display on my main monitor and for my home PC desktop to be visible on the second monitor.

Is there a way to stop the RDP display taking over the entire two monitor display space?

Comment: I am not certain but see if (in Advanced RDP options) "Use all monitors" is checked.  Try unchecking it

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do this if anyone was interested.

In the display options of the RDP connection box, I reduced the display size from the max down to the resolution of my main monitor.

When the connection completed, it started in smaller window size, which when maximised, only filled my main monitor, leaving my secondary monitor to still display my home desktop.